Minimum temperature for pocket lighters
I recently tried to use several new Ronson and Bic  pocket lighters when camping in -10 deg C weather. The lighters failed to light.
I've heard that the lighters need to be warmed, such as in one's hands, in order for the lighters to work properly.
That makes me wonder, what's the minimum required temperature for ignition? I'm aware I can use matches as an alternative. I'd still like to know a bit more about the temperature limitations of lighters.

Doesn't that depend on the fuel?

It's also to do with the reduced gas pressure at lower temperature, and the boiling point of butane is just below 0°C. Below that temperature it doesn't want to evaporate quickly. It's not quite the same, but compare a boiling kettle to a cup of hot water.
It's a good idea to carry the lighter in an inner pocket so it is readily usable.
In the old days, the tinder, flint and steel would be kept in a tinderbox, in a dry place such as next to the body. The non-electric butane lighter is a modern implementation of this, with its flint, ridged steel wheel, and gas. Of course there are piezoelectric models now too.
It's also a good idea to carry some dry paper and a little dry kindling. At each camp fire, cut and dry some more kindling for the next night.

One thing that works well as a starter is dryer lint smeared with vaseline.

Below its boiling point, no gas will leave its container. On the other hand, the usual substance to fill such lighters is a mixture of propane, isobutane and butane that has boiling point anywhere between -16C (pure propane) and -0.5C (pure butane). As one can guess, butane is cheaper. Good lighters work at -15C and any lighter works at any temperature as long as it is kept in an internal pocket.

@ItalianPhilosopher Interesting. I wonder if the dryer lint option only works well for people who don’t have pets. My dryer lint is always full of cat hair. I don’t know how well cat hair burns, but the smell might be enough of a deterrent on its own.

@User1974 hair does burn. There is the old saw "How do you make a cat bark?" Answer "Throw a match on it and it will go woof!"

@fraxinus the vapour pressure isn't zero below boiling point, and some gas will get out (just like how cold water eventually evaporates). However the pressure is insufficient for the nozzle to work as designed.

@User1974 it burns, but as you say, stinks horribly, and doesn't burn very well. Drier lint also contains a lot of plastic if you dry synthetic fabrics. That's not great either - it usually burns but the fumes and pollution are worse than with cotton

@ChrisH My experience with bigger propane-butane containers, as well as the bare physics, suggest that below the particular boiling point, when you open the container it is not the gas coming out, it is air entering in.
